# Regex to find lines that do not contain captured group

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I am trying to find logging lines in a project that log a throwable incorrectly. Examples of correct and incorrect usage:

```java
// Correct
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.error(className, "something went wrong", e);
}

// Incorrect, exception not logged
catch (Throwable t)
{
    String errMsg = "something went wrong";
    Log.fatal(className, errMsg);
}

// Incorrect, exception name concatenated instead of providing exception to print stacktrace
catch (IOException exception)
{
    Log.error(className, "Unable to read file " + exception);
}
```

Also shown are variants in exception types and names of the exception variable.

My current expression that's gotten me the closest is `catch\s*\(\w+\s+(\w+)\)\s*\{[\s\S]*Log\s*\.\w+\(\s*\w+,[\s\S]*(?!,\b\1\b\);)\);`. It matches the start of a `catch` block and captures the variable name used to hold the exception, then tries to find a `Log.<level>(` line that does *not* end with the exception variable as the last parameter, i.e. `, e);` It skips over the first example above and captures the other two.

The issue: I tried testing the expression here https://regexr.com/7p58l and it's missing an important case: where there's another place the logging is done correctly, regex does not find the first instance where it's done incorrectly.

```java
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // Regex should capture here, but does not
    Log.error(className, "something something exception");
}

void someMethod() {
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Because this line hits the negative lookahead
        Log.error(className, "something something exception", e);
    }
}
```

All my attempts at adding characters after the negative lookahead seem to break it in some form. What needs to be added to find all the incorrect cases?

This is being put into Intellij's global find, so if a tool in Intellij would work better that would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe to parse src files as text and process them logically with some script is better than messing with regex.

Comment: See if using the `Eclipse` compiler (instead of `javac`) on your project with `-err:+unusedExceptionParameter` as an additional command line parameter helps. Then, find the usages of the logging methods that don't take an Exception type for an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you can use a regular expression that ensures there is no correct logging of the exception within the catch block. The key is to make sure that if there is any logging within the catch block, it doesn't log the exception properly. Here's a modified regular expression that should work for your case:

```
catch\s*\(\w+\s+(\w+)\)\s*\{[\s\S]*?Log\.(?!error\s*\(\s*\w+,\s*"[^"]*",\s*\1\s*\);)[^\r\n;]*;\s*[\s\S]*?\}
```

Comment: This is very close to working, I changed `error` to `\w+` to also catch any variations in logging level and it's exactly what I need. However, it doesn't skip over lines of the form 
`String errMsg = "error: ";
Log.error(className, errMsg + obj.getInfo(), e);`
which is correct logging. The number of times something like the above occurs is slim, though, so I'm happy with the finding regex hitting just a few false positives